# There are 5 brothers

Tags: riddle, anagram

> If the first one is the stone, you will be very rich if you have a kilo of it
>   The second one is an evil one, he love wars, no love inside him.
>   The third one has many caps, he love computers, especially linux distribution.
>   The forth one has very long hair.
>   The fifth one is the victim of an evil destroyer.

**What are they?**

**They have yet another brother, who/what is it?**

Hint 1

> Our names have same length.

Hint 2

> Check the added tag

Comment: I thought of the 5 moons of Pluto, but am not able to line them all up properly. Many caps = Kerberos/Cerberus - 3-headed dog, also a popular authentication mechanism in computers, long hair = Hydra.

Comment: @Phylyp: Nice guess, but they have no connection to pluto.

Comment: Just curious - are there 6 brothers? Based on this sentence "They still have a brother"

Comment: @Phylyp: yes 6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I'll give it a try. Not totally satisfied with my solution, feels like using a lexical crowbar here, but still too close not to mention it. And if my feeling is right that the first one is already the hardest, and the last one is rubbish, then I might be up to something.

> Sorry, couldn't resist :-)

So I guess the first brother is

> "Hardest" - If you had a kilo(gram?) of the hardest stone (say diamond), that could make you rather rich.

The description of the second sounds quite like my old nemesis

> "Hatreds"

to me. Although I don't like too much that this brother comes in plural now.

The third brother would be the

> Fedora sporting "RedHats"

The fourth brother seems to be

> "Threads"

The fifth gives me the most problems. Maybe the one I have in mind is merely an ugly cousin of this family. I'm thinking of

> "Dearths" - With assuming the evil destroyer is Hunger, a horseman of the Apocalypse, who certainly leaves dearths wherever he rides.

If that's mostly correct so far, than this is a family of

> anagrams, as the tags heavily suggest

and the last brother is just wasted

> or "Trashed", to be precise

Or maybe he is good at bar sports and

> He darts?

Or the patron saint of gossip

> St Heard

OK, now it's getting silly.

What do you say Jamal? Did I round up the bunch of guys you were looking for?

Comment: If the brothers are slightly shorter than I assumed, the fifth brother could be the one (or rather exactly not the one) from the DC universe, which was ravaged by the shadowy minions of an evil destroyer. But then the stony brother would be too short for me to find any way he might make me rich, no matter how I look at him. And the sixth brother would probably elude me as well.

Comment: Congrats! You get all the answer correctly.

Comment: He darts and St Heard are not among them. Maybe they are just cousins, because they consist of 2 words.

Comment: Wow, cool! - With the 2 words rule being cousins, however, we should have a close look at who exactly the parents of brother three are. Seems he might just be a cousin as well, posing for a brother :-)